# How to get ENTIRELY a project from a CVS repository?

Tags: eclipse, download, repository, cvs

Let's better specify the question:

I'm looking for a way to download *ALL relative files* of more eclipse projects from a *CVS repository*.

When I said *all relative files*, I meant: I want also dowload from CVS repository files listed into `.cvsignore` file that normally are ignored.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way. `.cvsignore` lists the files that must not be stored inside the CVS repository. So obviously, they aren't stored inside. So there's no way to get them from the repository.